# What is the result of this byte operations?

Tags: byte, javacard

I find out that in APDU messages when you have to represent a number like 511 you write 0x01 0xFF not 0x1FF. And if you want to recreate the number you do the operation

```
short number = (short) (b1<<8 | b2 & 0xFF);
```

where b1 is 0x01 and b2 is 0xFF. Why we have to make this operation and what is the significance of b1<<8  and b2 & 0xFF? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'll rename your variables. b1 will be called B1 and b2 has lower significance and will be called B0 in below code. Then b31 to b0 will indicate bit positions instead, because that's what I'm used to. b31 will be the most significant position of an integer, and b0 the least significant position.

Note that all Java math operations result in an `int`. This plays merry hell with the Java Card runtime that usually doesn't have `int`, but let's continue the explanation.

So first the byte is converted to an `int`. If the topmost bit of `B1` is set to `1` then the byte has a negative value and bits b31 to b8 will be set to `1` as well. That is called *sign extension* for Java. This is happening because all integers in Java are signed (with the possible exception of `char`, but that's missing anyway from Java Card). If it didn't you would get a different negative `int` value if the `byte` value was negative.

`B1 << 8` simply shifts all the bits from position b7 to b0 of the byte (i.e. all the bits) into the location b15 to b8 of the resulting integer. First the byte is converted to an integer though.

For your calculation you will get:

```
00000001                            // B1 input, 0x01
00000000_00000000_00000000_00000001 // B1 as int
00000000_00000000_00000001_00000000 // B1 shifted 8 to the left
```

Now for the second part. Well, first we have to convert to integer again using sign bit extension. However, we cannot use OR with the previous value because of the possible sign bit extension: all top bits in b15 to b8 would be set to 1! That's why we mask the all the bits of the byte using bit wise AND, to undo the sign extension.

```
11111111                            // B0 input, 0xFF (-1 decimal)
11111111_11111111_11111111_11111111 // B0 as int, with sign extension, (-1 decimal)
00000000_00000000_00000000_11111111 // B0 as int, after & 0xFF
```

Great so now we OR the two (XOR would also work, but yeah)

```
00000000_00000000_00000001_1111111  // B1 is now before B0
```

And finally we cast to `short`:

```
00000001_11111111                   // which means removing the leftmost 16 bits
```

and there we are.

Note that we don't have to perform the `& 0xFF` trick for B1, because we throw away bit b31 to b16 anyway when we cast to short. So it doesn't matter if they contain a zero or a one valued bit.

A more readable option - in case optimization is not required - is to simply use [`makeShort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/framework/Util.html#makeShort(byte,%20byte)) by the way. It is more than likely that it does the exact same thing.

Comment: If this answers your question, then please accept it and or upvote it. If it doesn't please explain that something is missing. Sorry for the late answer, but not all questions can get my attention in time.

Comment: Hello, anybody there?